# Split each element of tuple into new line

Tags: python

I have a problem to split each element of tuple into new line.

I have to define my own class Songs and I have to use into this class _ _ init _ _ which should contain arguments: self, lyrics. Into that class I have to create method sing_me which is going to split every element of tuple into new lines.

I have to contain this line in main function:

```
Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!']).
```

I have really no idea how can I do this without converting that tuple into string but I can't really do it :/.

Do you have any solutions how can I do it?

Here's my code in which I'm stuck:

```
class Songs:
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics
    def sing_me:
        # don't know here what should I do

def main():
    Let_go = Songs(['When it"s black, ', 'Take a little time to hold yourself, ', 'Take a little time to feel around, ', 'Before it"s gone!'])
```

Output should look like:
When it"s black,

Take a little time to hold yourself,
Take a little time to feel around,
Before it"s gone!

Comment: I don't understand what is supposed to happen when `sing_me` is called. Did you mean: `for line in self.lyrics: print(line)`?

Comment: Note that what you are passing into the class as `lyrics` isn't a tuple, but a list. Perhaps you're having trouble because you're not looking for ways to iterate over a list (although most basic solutions would work for tuples as well)

Comment: Here's the code, if you can figure out how to decode it: `92923736962797c6e266c6563782e696f6a6e222e6c5228247e696270702020202a0a39266c656378256d6f576e6963702665646` :)

Comment: I think it would help you to try and be more precise in your problem statement and terminology. For example "[I need to] split each element of tuple into new line" should really be something like "[I need to] print each line of a song's lyrics on a new line".

Answer (score 1):

To split the tuple with newlines, you need to call the `"\n".join()` function. However, you need to first convert all of the elements in the tuple into strings.

The following expression should work on a given tuple:

```
"\n".join(str(el) for el in mytuple)
```

*Note that this is different from converting the entire tuple into a string. Instead, it iterates over the tuple and converts each element into its own string.*